# Property 'responseSuccess' does not exist on type '{ ResponseHandler: { responseSuccess: (response: any) => boolean; }; }'.ts(2339)

Tags: typescript

when I using the `responseSuccess` function in typescript like this:

```
if(ResponseHandler.responseSuccess(result)) {
}
```

the compiler shows error:

```
Property 'responseSuccess' does not exist on type '{ ResponseHandler: { responseSuccess: (response: any) => boolean; }; }'.ts(2339)
```

this is how to import the `ResponseHandler`:

```
import  ResponseHandler  from "js-wheel/index";
```

this is how to export the `ResponseHandler` in the public lib `index.ts` file:

```
import  ResponseHandler  from "./src/net/rest/ResponseHandler";

export default {
    ResponseHandler
}
```

this is how to define the `ResponseHandler` in the public lib:

```
const ResponseHandler = {
    responseSuccess:(response:any) => {
        if(response.statusCode === "200" && response.resultCode === "200"){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

export default ResponseHandler
```

why did this happen? what should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: With your current code, can you please try this... `ResponseHandler.ResponseHandler.responseSuccess(result)`??

Comment: it works,thank you! that means It no need to export the `ResponseHandler ` in the root `index.ts`?@NalinRanjan

Comment: I think `export default { ResponseHandler }` is the problem. Can you try making it `export default ResponseHandler` and see if the first way works?

Comment: If I need to export multiple Handler, what should I do? make a multiline with multi export? @NalinRanjan

Comment: There is a restriction when it comes to `default export`. There can be only 1 `default export` per module. However, if you want to export many, don't qualify the `export` with `default`. But then, the corresponding `import` forms will have to be adjusted. The way one imports `default export`(s) is different from the way one imports from regular modules.